# Implementing a fixed size, immutable, and specialized vector

Tags: scala, autoboxing, specialized-annotation

For performance and safety I would like to implement a fixed-size vector which is both immutable and specialized (I need fast arithmetics). My first idea was to use the `@specialized` annotation (because I need both integers and reals).

Here is a first try:

```
package so
class Vec[@specialized A] private[so] ( ary: Array[A] ) {
  def apply( i: Int ) = ary(i)
}
```

However, when I analyze the resulting bytecode with `javap`, I can see that the elements are still boxed. For instance:

```
public double apply$mcD$sp(int);
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   iload_1
   2:   invokevirtual   #33; //Method apply:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
   5:   invokestatic    #83; //Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.unboxToDouble:(Ljava/lang/Object;)D
   8:   dreturn
```

It looks like arrays are not specialized which seems silly, because arrays are specialized on the JVM.

Is there something I can still do to reach my goal ?

Comment: What version are you using? It looks fine for me with 2.9.2.

Comment: I tried with both 2.9.2 and 2.8.2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are likely looking at the code compiled to Vec.class. According to [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-user/browse_thread/thread/e8aef5df5e943e21?pli=1) the specialization occurs in subclasses. This can be verified in the REPL:

```
scala> class Vec[@specialized A] ( ary: Array[A] ) {
     |   def apply( i: Int ) = ary(i)
     | }
defined class Vec

scala> new Vec( Array[Int](1) ).getClass
res0: java.lang.Class[_ <: Vec[Int]] = class Vec$mcI$sp
```

As you can see for `Int` it is using the subclass `Vec$mcI$sp`. And if you run javap on that class you will see that it is infact specializing the code properly. This is what the apply method looks like in `Vec$mcI$sp.class` using javap:

```
  public int apply(int);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_0       
         1: iload_1       
         2: invokevirtual #13                 // Method apply$mcI$sp:(I)I
         5: ireturn
```

Which I suppose is what you want when using `Int`.